# How to parse a method return data as params inside another function in angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want the return data(object) am getting in below TextBoxChanged() method to be parsed in another component method as params. So that i can do some post API calls based on the params.

When am trying to access the return data from TextBoxChanged() in another component am getting property undefined since this method will trigger only on input field.

```
<input class="star" type="text" [(ngModel)]="search" id ={{Name}}" (input)="TextBoxChanged()"/>

globaldata: any;
TextBoxChanged(){
 const myFormInputs = document.getElementsByClassName("star")
 const myFormData = Array.prototype.filter.call(myFormInputs, 
 function(anElement) {
   this.globaldata = anElement.value;
 })
}
```

In my second component

```
ngOnInit() {console.log(this.comp1.globaldata)};
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: kindly find the code.

Comment: @user3109801 can you share the code where you are getting undefined

Comment: @FahadRehman code posted. As you see in second component am getting undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the Variable in the TS File

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})


export class AppComponent  {
 name : string;   // this is variable

 onTextChange(){
    console.log(this.name);
 }
}
```

and bind that variable with the text field in your TS File

```
<input type = "text" name = "name"
         placeholder = "name" 
         [(ngModel)]="name"
         ngModel (ngModelChange)="onTextChange()" >
```

and here is working code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jmvexs

and If you wanted to read about ngModel here is the link https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel